# Vuetable-2 : while implementing checkbox, only showing checkbox in first header row

Tags: vue-tables-2

here is link to what i have done. https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetable-2-data-mode-with-pagination-using-data-manager-prop-9gv99

Answer (score 0):

```
    import { VuetableFieldCheckbox } from "vuetable-2";
    {
       name: VuetableFieldCheckbox,
       titleClass: 'center aligned',
       dataClass: 'center aligned'
    }
```

maybe due to update of vuetable, it must config like this.
working with me

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by registering the `VuetableFieldCheckbox` component globally. This is accomplished by adding these lines to the project's `main.js` file:

```
import { VuetableFieldCheckbox } from 'vuetable-2'

Vue.component('vuetable-field-checkbox', VuetableFieldCheckbox)
```

Note: *any* special field component that is referenced by the `name: '__some-component'` convention in a field definition must be registered globally in the same fashion as shown above.